# Cpp error, Including multiple files in Visual studio 2012

Tags: c++

I have tried to create multiple Cpp files on visual studio 2012, my code parts are here:

**externTest.ccp**

```
// externTest.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//
#include "...\externTest\externTest\write.h"
//////////////////
// Global variables
/////////////////
int Count = 5;
/////////////////
// Extern functions
/////////////////
extern void write_extern ();
int main()
{
    int count = Count;
    write_extern();
    getchar ();
    return 0;
}
```

**write.h**

```
#ifndef WRITE_H
#define WRITE_H

////////////////////////
// Includes
////////////////////////
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
////////////////////////
// Variables
////////////////////////
extern int count;
////////////////////////
// Function prototype
////////////////////////
void write_extern (void);
///////////////////////
#endif // !WRITE_H
```

**write.cpp**

```
// write.ccp
//////////////////
// Includes
/////////////////
#include <...\externTest\externTest\write.h>
////////////////////
// Functions definition
////////////////////
void write_extern ()
{
    cout<< "Count is: \t" << count;
}
```

Finally  get the following error, which is basically not recognizing the **write.h** file
even I that the path is correctly defined:

> falouji\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\externtest\externtest\write.cpp(5): warning C4627: '#include <...\externTest\externTest\write.h>': skipped when looking for precompiled header use
>   1>          Add directive to 'stdafx.h' or rebuild precompiled header

Finally thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: Small remark: you have different `count`s: one `Count`, the other `count`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made a project that uses precompiled headers, so compiler looks for #include "stdafx.h" line as first include in the .cpp files, you can change this in the following way:

1) Right click the file in the solution view and open properties

2) Expand the `C/C++` subsection

3) Under `Precompiled Headers` and set `Create/Use Precompiled Header` to `Not Using Precompiled Headers`

Or just make an empty project and add your files to it, whichever is best.

Comment: Thank you very much, it#s the solution :)

Answer (score 2):

You either have to include `stdafx.h`, or disable [precompiled headers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dxawkbx.aspx) in the project options.